# How to solve conversion error in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please let me know the issue with following query I am trying to join on `msg_id` in some cases message id will be hexadecimal so I am converting to decimal and joining but I get this error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'e52b7ff2-0607-4b84-b326-7268af76f41d' to data type int.

This is the code:

```
select * 
from ODS..RPL1 a 
left join SAP_T1..RPL1 b on a.Mobileno = b.Mobileno 
                         and a.Trans_ID = b.Trans_ID 
                         and (case 
                                 when charindex('-', a.msg_id) > 0 
                                    then a.MSG_ID 
                                 when ISNUMERIC(a.MSG_ID + 'e0') = 1 
                                    then a.MSG_ID  
                                 when ISNUMERIC(a.MSG_ID + 'e0') = 0 
                                      and CHARINDEX('-', a.msg_id) = 0 
                                    then CONVERT(int, CONVERT(VARBINARY, a.MSG_ID, 2)) end) =
                               (case 
                                   when charindex('-', b.msg_id) > 0 
                                      then b.MSG_ID 
                                   when ISNUMERIC(b.MSG_ID + 'e0') = 1 
                                      then b.MSG_ID  
                                   when ISNUMERIC(b.MSG_ID + 'e0') = 0 
                                        and CHARINDEX('-', b.msg_id) = 0 
                                      then CONVERT(int, CONVERT(VARBINARY, b.MSG_ID, 2)) end) 
where 
    a.msg_id = 'e52b7ff2-0607-4b84-b326-7268af76f41d'
```

Comment: could you provide us more information about your table ?

Comment: could you please provide reference value for "a.msg_id"?

Comment: The error suggests the msg_id column of ODS..RPL1 is int but your literal is uniqueidentifier string literal.

Comment: hi all thanks for your quick replay i got solution i really thanks for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have logic like this:

```
(case when charindex('-', a.msg_id) > 0
      then  a.MSG_ID
      when ISNUMERIC(a.MSG_ID + 'e0') = 1
      then a.MSG_ID
      when ISNUMERIC(a.MSG_ID + 'e0') = 0 and
           CHARINDEX('-', a.msg_id) = 0
      then CONVERT(int, CONVERT(VARBINARY, a.MSG_ID, 2))
 end)
```

A `case` expression only returns one type.  In this case, the type will be an integer, because that is the most restrictive (that is how the conversion rules work).  Hence, returning `msg_id` will fail with the conversion to an integer.

Adding an explicit conversion back to a string will fix the immediate problem:

```
(case when charindex('-', a.msg_id) > 0
      then  a.MSG_ID
      when ISNUMERIC(a.MSG_ID + 'e0') = 1
      then a.MSG_ID
      when ISNUMERIC(a.MSG_ID + 'e0') = 0 and
           CHARINDEX('-', a.msg_id) = 0
      then CAST(CONVERT(int, CONVERT(VARBINARY, a.MSG_ID, 2)) as VARCHAR(255))
 end)
```

Whether this does what you want is unclear, because your question does not specify that.  If this doesn't do what you want (but it does fix the conversion), then ask *another* question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: @RamThakur if the answer is correct then you should accept it